# Should I initialize a new instance of .fileSystemObject in every module or should I strive to reference the object from the main module?

Tags: excel, vba, module

I use `fileSystemObject` in several modules of my project. Is it better to make an instance of FSO in every module or reference the FSO from my main `MdApp` module? As in

```
set fso = MdApp.fso
```

Seems to work either way, but maybe there are some important implicit things I should know about?

Comment: You can do as you suggested only if `fso` is declared on top of a standard module (in the declarations area). `Public fso As Object`.  If you do so, no need to mention the module name. You simple use it as `Set objTxt = fso.OpenTextFile(fullFileName, 1)`. **You firstly must set it like**: `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`. You can do that in the `Workbook_Open` event, but you can do it from any module. In my opinion, if you do not use it very often, it is not too good to keep the memory loaded with this object. It is not too complicated to declare and set it in each `Sub`.

Comment: Or use early binding and simple declare it `Public fso As New FileSystemObject`. Of course, making a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there is no need to create more than one instance of a FileSystemObject. However, I think it is not a good idea to rely on a global variable. Problem is that once your code is reset (eg because of a runtime error or a recompile) the reference is gone and you need to create a new instance.

Put a small function is your `MdApp`-module:

```
Private fso As FileSystemObject
' Or use the followin declaration if you prefer late binding
' Private fso As Object

Public Function getFso()

    If fso Is Nothing Then
        Set fso = New FileSystemObject
        ' or use the following when you prefer late binding:
        ' Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    End If
    Set getFso = fso
End Function
```